# How to find IWebElement in other IWebElement with Selenium Web?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

I'm trying to get some IWebElement in other specific IWebElement which I find, but it doesn't work.

Here I find all of the repeated HTML blocks, it works OK:

```
List<IWebElement> allIwebElementBlocks = InitData.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'card-trade-point')]/.")).ToList();
```

But when I'm trying to find IWebElement in IWebElement (which I have in List) this code give always information about the first element in List.

Target part of Html page:

```
<div class="LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--container-217">
    <div class="MuiPaper-root-18 MuiPaper-elevation1-21 MuiPaper-rounded-19 MuiCard-root-242 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--item-218" id="card-trade-point-4">
        <div class="MuiCardContent-root-243">
            <h2 class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-headline-145 MuiTypography-gutterBottom-157" id="attr-name">
                Test 223 name</h2>
            <p class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-body1-149" id="attr-address">Address test3</p>
            <span class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-caption-150">Address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="MuiCardActions-root-244 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--buttonsWrapper-219">
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-text-248 MuiButton-textPrimary-249 MuiButton-outlined-254 MuiButton-outlinedPrimary-255 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-registers"><span class="MuiButton-label-247">Box</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-text-248 MuiButton-textPrimary-249 MuiButton-outlined-254 MuiButton-outlinedPrimary-255 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-cashiers"><span class="MuiButton-label-247">User</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-contained-257 MuiButton-containedPrimary-258 MuiButton-raised-260 MuiButton-raisedPrimary-261 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--editButton-220 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-edit"><span class="MuiButton-label-247"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-69 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--iconEdit-221" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 0 0-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root-18 MuiPaper-elevation1-21 MuiPaper-rounded-19 MuiCard-root-242 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--item-218" id="card-trade-point-9">
        <div class="MuiCardContent-root-243">
            <h2 class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-headline-145 MuiTypography-gutterBottom-157" id="attr-name">
                One more name</h2>
            <p class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-body1-149" id="attr-address"><i>Empty</i></p>
            <span class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-caption-150">Address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="MuiCardActions-root-244 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--buttonsWrapper-219">
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-text-248 MuiButton-textPrimary-249 MuiButton-outlined-254 MuiButton-outlinedPrimary-255 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-registers"><span class="MuiButton-label-247">Box</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-text-248 MuiButton-textPrimary-249 MuiButton-outlined-254 MuiButton-outlinedPrimary-255 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-cashiers"><span class="MuiButton-label-247">User</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-contained-257 MuiButton-containedPrimary-258 MuiButton-raised-260 MuiButton-raisedPrimary-261 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--editButton-220 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-edit"><span class="MuiButton-label-247"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-69 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--iconEdit-221" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 0 0-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="MuiPaper-root-18 MuiPaper-elevation1-21 MuiPaper-rounded-19 MuiCard-root-242 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--item-218" id="card-trade-point-2">
        <div class="MuiCardContent-root-243">
            <h2 class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-headline-145 MuiTypography-gutterBottom-157" id="attr-name">
                Third name</h2>
            <p class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-body1-149" id="attr-address">Address xx</p>
            <span class="MuiTypography-root-140 MuiTypography-caption-150">Address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="MuiCardActions-root-244 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--buttonsWrapper-219">
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-text-248 MuiButton-textPrimary-249 MuiButton-outlined-254 MuiButton-outlinedPrimary-255 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-registers"><span class="MuiButton-label-247">Box</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-text-248 MuiButton-textPrimary-249 MuiButton-outlined-254 MuiButton-outlinedPrimary-255 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-cashiers"><span class="MuiButton-label-247">User</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
            <button tabindex="0" class="MuiButtonBase-root-272 MuiButton-root-246 MuiButton-contained-257 MuiButton-containedPrimary-258 MuiButton-raised-260 MuiButton-raisedPrimary-261 MuiButton-sizeSmall-269 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--editButton-220 MuiCardActions-action-245" type="button" id="btn-edit"><span class="MuiButton-label-247"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-69 LoadNamespace-TradePointsList--iconEdit-221" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34a.9959.9959 0 0 0-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"></path><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path></svg></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-275"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full method code:

```
public IEnumerable<Block> GetCards()
    {
        List<IWebElement> allIwebElementBlocks = InitData.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id, 'card-trade-point')]/.")).ToList();
        var outBlockList = new List<Block>();
        foreach (IWebElement webBlock in allIwebElementBlocks)
        {
            //Here I'm trying to get information about IWebElement in a current loop, but I receive first element in List*
            var tmpName = webBlock.FindElement(By.XPath("//h2[contains(@id, 'attr-name')]")).Text;
            var blc = new Block(webBlock);
            outBlockList.Add(blc);
        }
        return outBlockList;
    }
```

In the end, I want to find IWebElements from second and next elements for working with it.
*For example, I need to get the text "Third name", but I receive text "Test 223 name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `var tmpName = webBlock.FindElement(By.XPath("//h2[contains(@id, 'attr-name')]")).Text;` to `var tmpName = webBlock.FindElement(By.XPath(".//h2[contains(@id, 'attr-name')]")).Text;`.

This should work (see details [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3203)).